# Template.FindName does not work if I set Name from code

Tags: wpf, xaml

As you can see in code below, I have descendant of ScrollViewer, and set Name of MyScrollView in ctor. But when I try using MyScrollViewer in control template I cannot find one via Template.FindName

If I change `<local:MyScrollViewer />` to `<local:MyScrollViewer Name=""PART_ContentHost"" />` code works as expected, but I am looking for solution without changing XAML.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var parserContext = new ParserContext
        {
            XamlTypeMapper = new XamlTypeMapper(new string[0]),
            XmlnsDictionary =
            {
                { "", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" },
                { "x", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" },
                { "local", "clr-namespace:" + typeof(MyScrollViewer).Namespace + ";assembly=" + typeof(MyScrollViewer).Assembly.FullName}
            }
        };
        var template = (ControlTemplate)XamlReader.Parse(@"
    <ControlTemplate TargetType=""TextBox"">
        <Border>
             <local:MyScrollViewer />
             <!--<local:MyScrollViewer Name=""PART_ContentHost""/> -->
        </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
", parserContext);
        // Name=""PART_ContentHost""
        Content = new MyTextBox { Template = template };
    }
}

public class MyScrollViewer: ScrollViewer
{
    public MyScrollViewer() => Name = "PART_ContentHost";
}
public class MyTextBox: TextBox
{
    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        var contentHost = Template.FindName("PART_ContentHost", this);
        if (contentHost == null)
            throw new Exception("Can not find PART_ContentHost");
    }
}
```

updated:
Even I put my control template into MainWindow.xaml (and remove from MainWindow ctor), it doesnot work.

```
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"        
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:MyTextBox" x:Key="TextBoxTemplate">
                <local:MyScrollViewer />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <local:MyTextBox Template="{StaticResource TextBoxTemplate}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constructor of `MyScrollViewer` will not be called on `template` creation with `XamlReader`, so the names <del>with which `MyScrollViewer` was created</del> are stored in internal dictionaries. See `template.ChildNames`. The constructor of `MyScrollViewer` will first being called, when `MyTextBox` becomes visible, but it's already too late.

Template being created from XAML and it notices the children names by parsing, without creation of children instances. Later the children instances will be created, but the template hold old names. So if you call `Template.FindNames` with new names, they will not be found.
Try

```
var contentHost = Template.FindName("2_T", this);
```

Comment: No, ctor is called

Comment: Did you meant, that constructor from MyScrollViewer being called?

Comment: On my side it being not called.

Comment: I mean, when I set breakpoint on line Name = "PART_ContentHost" ->> app stopped as this point, so ctor of MyScrollViewer is called. And Name of MyScrollViewer is setted.

Comment: Not by me. `public MyScrollViewer(){ Name = "PART_ContentHost";}` being not called. Can it be, that ctor being called on your side from another place, but not from `XamlReader `?

Comment: I updated my post, removed xmlreader from code. Breakpoint works. MyScrollViewer is used only in ControlTemplate. By stacktrace I see MyScrollViewer called from ApplyTemplate via Activator.CreateInstance. Screenshot: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1414Rbej6qZfpl7RfpnzYVZX2Ls3c2mcJ/view?usp=sharing  project: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Jkpmv3oKxrZx3Ex90fz8Y2mxIatZJUVj/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @ЕвгенийСавин `XamlParser` does it not another way as `XamlReader`.

Comment: @ЕвгенийСавин `XamlParser` does it not another way as `XamlReader`. What I mean -  template being created from XAML and it **notices the children names** by parsing, without creation of children instances. Later the children instances will be created, but the template hold old names.

Comment: Yes, I get it. It is very sadly what wpf hardwired to xaml

Answer (score 1):

> but I am looking for solution without changing XAML

Setting the name in the constructor of the `ScrollViewer` won't work. You have to set it in the template for it to be registered in the namescope of the template.

If you don't want to assign the element a `Name` in the template, you could wait for it to get created and then find it in the visual tree without using a name:

```
public class MyTextBox : TextBox
{
    public MyTextBox()
    {
        Loaded += MyTextBox_Loaded;
    }

    private void MyTextBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyScrollViewer sv = FindVisualChild<MyScrollViewer>(this);
        //...
    }

    private static T FindVisualChild<T>(Visual visual) where T : Visual
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(visual); i++)
        {
            Visual child = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(visual, i);
            if (child != null)
            {
                T correctlyTyped = child as T;
                if (correctlyTyped != null)
                {
                    return correctlyTyped;
                }

                T descendent = FindVisualChild<T>(child);
                if (descendent != null)
                {
                    return descendent;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```